# Apache directive for file downloads

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How do I create Apache directives in a `.htaccess` file that forces `.mp4` and `.pdf` to download? Currently they appear within the browser window. Instead, I would like a download file dialog box to appear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following into an .htaccess file:

```
<Files *.mp4>
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
<Files *.pdf>
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```