# PHP function readfile() only outputs file contents into firebug and not download

Tags: php, readfile

I'm trying to zip a file and then send to user download that file but it is not working. When it executes my php function, it only outputs the file contents into firebug and if the firebug is not on, it do nothing. The file I am trying to send is 2,9MB but I tried to send only a txt file with a single phrase and did not work. I already checked and the file is been created and the files added correctly.

```
$zipname = path . "arquivos/" . $file . ".zip";

touch($zipname);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$result = $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($result === true) {
    foreach ($Variable->Dados as $key => $value) {
        $zip->addFile(path . "arquivos/articulador_avaliacao/" . $value->arquivo, $value->arquivo_nome);
    }
    $zip->close();


    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($zipname) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must_revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($zipname);
}
unlink($zipname);
```

This executes through certain process: The user clicks on a  html tag with onclick function executing a javascript function, this javascript function uses ajax to send variables to a php file and then this code is executed.

Comment: You can not trigger a download directly from within an AJAX request - AJAX means a request _in the background_, the browser UI does not get involved here. Either use a direct link (if GET is enough to send the necessary parameters to the server) or a form (if you need to submit POST data), or go research how to trigger a download dialog from within JavaScript. (The latter will add considerable overhead, so the former is preferable IMHO.)

Answer (score 0):

I run your code, and it worked :) Maybe there is a problem with the browser interpretting the headers? Try with different browser and check your browser configuration.

Comment: I already tried... I presuming that is something in the apache configuration or some sort. Do you know something about it?

Comment: Maybe some plugin you have in the browser tryes to open the zip. Maybe you should try with the `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

Comment: You could try to force the download as attachment in the Apache .htaccess file directive, like posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056839/apache-directive-for-file-downloads), and restarting the server. But I doubt that this is the server-related issue

Comment: I tried today using XSendFile module but it does the same. The file is loaded but just appear in the firebug console if it is open and if it is closed, nothing happens. Tried to change several configuration in apache.conf but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Since I use javascript and AJAX, I did some research as [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) told me and I found my solution. Didn't need those headers in my php script and neither the readfile function.

When the client click on the button, a javascript function executes and send data to a PHP script through AJAX. This PHP script creates the zip file with the function **touch** and **ZipArchive** class and send the path to this file as an ajax response. In javascript I used this to send the file to client:

```
window.open(ajaxObject.response, '_blank');
```

It all worked perfectly.