# Can you make a file downloadable through Apache?

Tags: apache

Path = `/var/lib/foo.txt`

Is it possible to configure Apache so there would be some HTTP URL that would initiate a download of this file and how? 
**Without `.htaccess` file.**

And what would that URL be then? `localhost/var/lib/foo.txt`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache directive for file downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056839/apache-directive-for-file-downloads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as adding an alias directive within your apache config.

```
Alias '/bar' '/path/to/foo'
```

Then you'd access the resource publicly via something like `http://example.com/bar`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes create an .htaccess file in /var/lib/ (/var/lib/.htaccess) and add the following content:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .txt
```

That's all.

**EDIT:**

Without an .htaccess file you can use PHP code.

Here is an example:
Create a file in `public_html` or `www` folder and name it `download.php`
Paste the PHP code below and save your file. Now visit http://www.yoursite.com/download.php.
The file should download without any issue.

```
$fileName = 'my-foo-file.txt';
$filePath = '/var/lib/foo.txt';
if(!$filePath){
    die('File not found!');
} else {
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    readfile($filePath);
}
```

Comment: In your php solution, you'd be better to swap your conditional `if(!$filePath)` for `if(!is_readable($filePath))`, the latter tests to see if the file exists and is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file...  You can add different directives for different file types such as .txt, .pdf, .mp4 etc...

```
<Files *.txt>
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```