# Ho to create download link in django

Tags: python, django

I created a Django project which I use in Apache server.

The project simply edits an `.m3u` file when you press a button on a page, and generates a new `.m3u` file. The script works as intended.

Can Django generate a download link automatically for this newly generated `.m3u` file? I understand from many tutorials that I need to edit the `urls.py` and `view.py` files, but I need it to be done automatically.

Or another option would be to make the file downloadable via Apache directly if something like this is possible.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a guide or tutorial, which Stack Overflow is not. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is that is it possible Django can generate a download link automatically for this newly generated m3u file

Yes. I assume this is a static file located somewhere on the server. You can make file generator script/function return the location of generated file on server. The download URL can take location of this fileas a query parameter. You can make [this file available using Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392510/django-download-a-file).

> Or another option would be to make the file downloadable via apache diretly if something like this is possible.

Yes, you can. See [Can you make a file downloadable through Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758729/can-you-make-a-file-downloadable-through-apache)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Just to be clear, do I need to do any other setting in Django side in order to use Apache way?

Comment: No, simply download the file on a location on the server from where Apache can read them.