# Setting up URL query file download for apache

Tags: apache, url

So i have an apache server set up and running, but I want people to be able to download files with an URL query, like apache.com/get?cat.png will return file named cat.png in a folder if it exists and error if it doesn't? I'm very new on this, forgive me on any mistakes I have

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you share some code with us so we can see what you've already tried, and what will fit best with your code? Thanks!

Comment: emm Hello, I have tried nothing yet since I can't find any documents that seemed useful, and I came here because I had no clue at all on how to start doing it at all, figuring I would come here to get some resources to start with

Comment: Well, to start, is your cat.png file already on your server? If yes, one of these solutions might work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758729/can-you-make-a-file-downloadable-through-apache

Comment: so basically I want the user to access to say, example.com/foo.php?file=document.png&token=RandomToken, and the file would receive the file parameter and token in a function, and be able to return a file.
Edit: Sorry for the broken English, I'm not good at typing long sentences

Comment: so I would have like

file SomeFunction(string file,string token)

{

//handle data

return file;

}

is that possible? I'm unfamiliar with websites in general

Comment: All right, first things first: you mentioned you have an apache server set up and running. How did you set that up, and what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm currrently running it on windows but it's trivial to migrate it to ubuntu if need be, for windows I used apache louge and for ubuntu I just use the standard installation

Comment: And is the file you want to download on your server?

Comment: yes, I just want to use it as a way to share files with my friend